# What's the difference between these two function declarations?

Tags: javascript

Version 1:

```js
function myF() {
  var executed = false;
  return function() {
    if (!executed) {
      executed = true;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Ab"
    }
  };
};

myF();
```

Version 2:

```js
var myF = (function() {
  var executed = false;
  return function() {
    if (!executed) {
      executed = true;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Ab"
    }
  };
})();

myF();
```

Why the v2 works, and why the v1 not? What's the main difference between these two, when they are called?

Comment: The second one invokes the outer function immediately, and the first does not. Add `var myF2 = myF();  myF2();` to invoke the second inner function.

Comment: Also, if you're not already familiar with [IIFE's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), you may want to take a look.

Comment: not an exact dupe, but close https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 2 returns the result of an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), Version 1 is the same but doesn't invoke the expression. You *could* invoke it like `myF()()`,

```js
function myF() {
  var executed = false;
  return function() {
    if (!executed) {
      executed = true;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Ab"
    }
  };
};

myF()();
```

```html
<div id="demo">
</div>
```

Comment: There's really no such thing as "returning" an IIFE. The second one *is* an IIFE that returns its result, which is another function.

Comment: @doodlemeister Good point. Returns the result of an IIFE. Does that parse better?

Comment: Yep, makes more sense to me.